# Debian backup bashscript

Tags: debian, backup, bash

I'm hosting my own web server, and would like to regularly take a backup of my files. So I decided to write a bash script. However, I'm stuck with this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# /etc/init.d/backup
# version 0.3.9 2012-08-13 (YYYY-MM-DD)
backup(){

   NOW=`date "+%Y-%m-%d_%Hh%M"`
   tar -czvf  Backup${NOW}.tar.gz /var/www/
   mv Backup${NOW}.tar.gz /home/user/backup/

}
exit 0
```

I'm wondering how I will run it, how would I make it run every day at certain time.

Any help?

Comment: You may need to try rsnapshot http://www.rsnapshot.org/howto/ .. you don't have to reinvent the wheel buddy

Comment: Or rdiff-backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using rsync,

Rync Backup script -This will make a backup folder for today ,then sycn yesterdays files todays then it will rsync todays to be backed up.

```
#!/bin/sh

mkdir -p /storage/backups/`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d`-`date +\%A`/

rsync -avz /storage/backups/`date --date=yesterday +\%Y-\%m-\%d`-`date--date=yesterday    +\%A`/ /storage/backups/`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d`-`date +\%A`/

rsync -avz -e ssh  /var/www/ /storage/backups/`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d`-`date +\%A`/

# Definitions
sevendaysago=$(date --date='6 days ago' +%Y-%m-%d-%A)

# Delete backups from 7 days ago
rm -rf /storage/backups/$sevendaysago
```

you will need to run this to make scripts run-able

```
chmod u+x script.sh
```

In cron you will just need to add via crontab -e

```
@daily sh backupscript
```

Taken from [my blog](http://blog.timothydavidellis.com)

Comment: When I did @daily sh backup, it simply gave me `-bash: @daily: command not found
`

Comment: in terminal enter crontab -e to edit the users crontab then enter @daily sh /location of above script/backupscript.sh

Comment: And then reboot? When will it run?

Comment: It will then run at script once daily at mid night. It the same as putting 0 0 * * * in your crontab. You will not need to reboot. To test the script works go to the file location and run source "script name" this will execute the script and display any errors

Comment: Good! So it will delete any bacups older than 7 days?

Comment: Correct it will keep a seven day running backup and remove the ones older than this

Answer (score 2):

First, this script will not do anything. You just defined a function `backup` and did not call it. Just add a line like this below `exit 0`

```
backup
```

Cron is the best tool to run specific tasks/scripts regularly.